# Ubuntu 20:04, keyboard stopped working suddenly with this symbol constantly flickering on the screen

Tags: keyboard

I also use awesome VM and this doesn't seem to be an issue there. I've looked at a similar question but none of the answers provided could resolve this. I'm using a lenovo if that helps.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmYWE.jpg)

Comment: What program should be accepting keyboard input? Try opening a terminal emulator with `Ctrl-Alt-T` (together). Mouse click in the terminal window. Can you type, or do you still get the white NoNo?  Somewhere along the Keyboard->Host Operating System->VM Hypersupervisor->VM->Ubuntu path somebody's saying NO to keyboard input.

Comment: I can type occasionally, it goes away temporarily when I press the super key for a bit. How do I check the keyboard path? I can access the terminal.